# Store promises in multiple variables of async function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, promise, async-await

Is it possible to store the data of resolved promises in multiple variables using a async/await function?

E.g.

```
const urls = [
    'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users',
    'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts'
]

const getData = async function() {
    const Promises = urls.map(url => fetch(url))
    for await (let request of Promises) {
        const data = await request.json()
    }
}

getData()

// However, I want to store '/users' in 'const users', '/posts' in 'const posts' etc.
```

Comment: I don't understand the question.  What exactly do you need help with?  Your variable `Promises` will be an array of promises, but this is not the easiest way to get an array of data.

Comment: Is `Promise.all` that your want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be looking for

```
async function getData() {
    const promises = [
        'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users',
        'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts'
    ].map(url =>
        fetch(url).then(request => request.json())
    );
    const [users, posts] = await Promise.all(promises);
    console.log(users, posts);
}
```